Why am I getting an error loading a specific module(torch)?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\OpenCV\t.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

I uninstall and then reinstalled the module and also tried different versions of python too but nothing worked.

Could you provide the versions of OpenCV and Torch you're using in the environment?

yesterday I saw similar question - maybe it is even the same question

Failed to import pytorch fbgemm.dll or one of its dependencies is missing - windows - PyTorch Forums

python - import torch: How to fix OSError WinError 126, error loading fbgemm.dll or dependencies - Stack Overflow

similar question from yesterday: python - How do I resolve this error and get my code running? - Stack Overflow

Considering Pytorch Forums question you'll have to requires the Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC) runtime libraries to be installed on Windows systems.

[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer).

@AkshayVilasPatil torch==2.4 and opencv's latest version

I found a simple fix for this issue. Get a recent copy of libomp140.x86_64.dll, and put it in C:\Windows\System32. The latest versions of C++ redistributables or Visual Studio 2022 may not put that file on your machine like they used to. I got mine from another machine where I installed VS etc. over a year ago.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78794748/10549172

I found the solution for my problem recently. I just simply installed VC_redist.x64 and boom!!! Problem Solved
